# Check null and execute one or another one line

Tags: php, operators, ternary

I have this code:

```
    $red = "value";
    $resp = (($red && get("aaa")) ?: getb("aaa"));
    
    print $resp;
    
    function get($aaa)
    {
        return "aaa";
    }
    
    function getb($aaa)
    {
        return $aaa . "bbb";
    }
```

But in this case `$red && get("aaa")` code is assigning to `$resp`, but instead, I want that if `$red` is not null, execute `get("aaa")` and if `get("aaa")` returns false it executes `getb("aaa")`.

The code is doing fine when `$red` is null or `get("aaa")` is false, but when in this case is return true.

Is there anyway to do this in one line of code like this? Or I have to use ifs?

Comment: Check this [playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/L3P0U4z3Mo2EL3QQ), it should cover all your cases.

Comment: I'd use `if`s though. Nested operators like this are pretty hard to read and maintain for pretty much no gain (other than a few lines of code).

Comment: Thanks @DigitalDrifter it helped a lot.

Comment: @Jeto, yes it's true. Thanks